# promisePool is ignoring concurrency limit and running all promises at once

Tags: javascript, node.js

all.
I am trying to implement a PromisePool from [es6-promise-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-pool)
. However, when I run my code, all of the promises are executing at once instead of obeying the concurrency limit.

relevent code:

```
// individual promise
var writeGpsProjection = function(sensor, i){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    lgmsg = "running: sensor: " + sensor + "     iterator: " + i
    console.log(lgmsg)

    setTimeout(function () {
        resolvMsg = "done: sensor: " + sensor + "     iterator: " + i
        console.log(resolvMsg);
        resolve(resolvMsg);
    }, 2000)
})
}

// promise producer
var collectForThread = function () {
    var sensorKeys = Object.keys(sensorUpdates);
    i = 0;
    sensorKeys.forEach(function(sensor){
        if (i < sensorKeys.length){
            i++;
            command = writeGpsProjection(sensor, i)
            return command
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
}

concurrency = 3
async function gpsEngine(){
  while (true) {
    console.log(" ------ Running Thread ------  " + 
    Object.keys(sensorUpdates).length  +  " sensors to process:");

    var pool = new PromisePool(collectForThread, concurrency);
    pool.start()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Complete')
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log('All promises fulfilled')
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Some promise rejected: ' + error.message)
    })
    await timeMachines.sleep(8);

}
}

gpsEngine();
```

If there is a more simple solution, I would love to hear that also. My objective is, given a list of objects, run a process on each but limit the number running consecutively to a certain number because the real process will involve pulling records from a database, and various other resource intensive jobs. I am afraid that if I try to do all of them at once async-wise, it will lock me up. The while loop is because this is a process that will need to periodically run to process data in our lab server.

Comment: What are you expecting the function `collectForThread()` to return?

Comment: well, as I understand it, it should return a list of commands that each return a promise that will be executed by the PromisePool

Comment: I don't know anything about `PromisePool` so I don't want to post an answer, but `collectForThread()` doesn't return anything. Your `return command` is only returning from the `forEach` callback. You should probably use something like `return sensorKeys.map(...etc)`

Comment: awesome. thank you very much

Comment: ok, i did this  // promise producer
var collectForThread = function () {
    var sensorKeys = Object.keys(sensorUpdates);
    return sensorKeys.map((sensorKey, index) => {
        writeGpsProjection(sensorKey, index)
    });
}   but still getting the same result.  (sorry, cannot seem to format the comment would a link to a gist be better ? )

Comment: If you put `writeGpsProjection(sensorKey, index)` inside braces `{}` you need to use `return`. You can omit the braces and it will implicitly return the value.

Comment: good to know, thanks !